# Is there a php function to echo strings based on abbreviations provided?

Tags: php

I have an array named $lang as shown in the code section. I want to write a function that, based on the array $lang, would echo out complete strings instead of the abbreviations. The data is coming from mysql database.

I tried at my own but could not figure out a solution.

```
$lang = array();

$lang = array_merge($lang,array(
"NA" => "Not applicable",
"FA" => "Father",
"MO" => "Mother",
"IND" => "Independent",
));
```

Help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the possible content of the `@lang` array?

Comment: Pretty much similar kind of strings as shown.  I could extend the array by using:

Comment: $lang = array_merge($lang,array(
"BA" => "Bachelor of Arts",
"MA" => "Masters Degree",
));

Comment: Thanks, and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need but my guess is this

```
$lang = [
    "NA"  => "Not applicable",
    "FA"  => "Father",
    "MO"  => "Mother",
    "IND" => "Independent"
];
$lang = array_merge($lang, array( "BA" => "Bachelor of Arts", "MA" => "Masters Degree", ))
//Then you can do 
echo $lang['NA']; // will output => Not applicable
echo $lang['BA']; // will output => Bachelor of Arts
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly and you want to echo all *" ... complete strings instead of the abbreviations ..."*, then [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) is one possible approach:

```
<?php
$lang = array(
   "NA" => "Not applicable",
   "FA" => "Father",
   "MO" => "Mother",
   "IND" => "Independent"
);

echo "Array with values: ";
print_r(array_values($lang));
echo "<br>";

echo "Text with values: ";
echo implode(", ", array_values($lang));
echo "<br>";
?>
```

If you want to get the value of a specific item from an array, simply get this value by index:

```
<?php
$lang = array(
   "NA" => "Not applicable",
   "FA" => "Father",
   "MO" => "Mother",
   "IND" => "Independent"
);

echo $lang["NA"];
?>
```